# Calling several instances of java classes from native C code

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-native-interface

I'm trying to call several instances of a java class from c language. The code runs well for a single instance but fails when I try to call several instances of java classes.

There is a jar file and a supporting dll for the java classes, and the java classes are assumed to be a complete blackbox

```
JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM **jvm) {

JNIEnv *env;
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;

JavaVMOption options[4];

options[0].optionString = "-Djava.compiler=none";

//Path to the java source code

options[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=G:\\dtk_testing\\dtk_test\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DTK Software\\DTK ANPR SDK\\Bin\\Java\\DTKANPR.jar";

options[2].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=C:\\Windows\\System32";

//options[3].optionString = "-verbose";


vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; 
vm_args.nOptions = 4;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;

jint ret =JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
```

invoking a class using the following method in C:
The value j is a parameter that I pass on to the java code, which in turn calls an image with that particular serial number

```
void invoke_class(JNIEnv *env, char *str)
{

jclass DTK_ANPR_Test;
jmethodID dtk_anpr;

jint k=2;

jvalue *val=(jvalue *)malloc(sizeof(jvalue));
val->i=(jint *)malloc(sizeof(jint));
(val->i)=k;

    DTK_ANPR_Test = (*env)->FindClass(env, "DTKANPRTest");

    dtk_anpr = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, DTK_ANPR_Test, "anpr", "   (I)V");


    (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethodA(env, DTK_ANPR_Test, dtk_anpr, val);
}
```

Later I call this method, 'invoke_class' wherever I need to run the java class.

I was thinking that running the code in parallel (using openmp or mpi) would do, but I'm still not sure as to how I can proceed further

P.S. I don't have any good idea about openmp or mpi

Comment: The java method you called is static, how can you call this method in several different instance?

Comment: hello @alijandro , I've tried making it non-static but it crashes. I've just removed the 'static' word. Is there anything else that I need to do. Infact I've tried caching the object, class and method id's but the result is still the same

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean, is not "instances" since you are invoking a static method, but multiple threads invoking the same static method?

If that is the case, your first invocation will work because the thread used, called `JNI_CreateJavaVM` which becomes your java main thread. When JVM is created it attaches the current native thread to the JVM.

The `JNIEnv` that you get, is only valid for that 1 thread which originally created the JVM. If you want to call the same method from additional native threads, you need to attach those threads as well, using the JNI call `AttachCurrentThread`.

Note, you will have a different `JNIEnv` instance for each thread.

Hope that helps.

PS: if you are passing a simple jint argument to a java method, I would suggest you use `CallStaticVoidMethod(env, DTK_ANPR_Test, dtk_anpr, 2)` instead of needlessly allocating memory to pass an integer, which never seems to be released, so this will be a memory leak.

Comment: Hello Mark, sorry for replying late. I've tried caching the required object (by using NewGlobalRef) and class id's as well, the problem remains the same. 'JavaVM *jvm' has also been kept global and I tried attaching threads but the program crashes after returning to the first call. In addition.